# Transform Recursive function to Iterative function

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, iteration

I am trying to convert this recursive function to an iterative one

```
void printPath(int parent[], int j) 
{ 

    // Base Case
    if (parent[j] == - 1) 
        return; 

    printPath(parent, parent[j]); 

    printf("%d ", j); 
}
```

This is the OUTPUT

```
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 7 6 5 4
0 7 6 5
0 7 6
0 7
0 1 2 8
```

This is what I have tried but the output is incorrect

```
void printPath(int parent[], int j) 
{   
    int temp = parent[j];

    while (temp != - 1)
    {
        temp = parent[temp];
        printf("%d ", temp);

    }
}
```

This is the OUTPUT [incorrect]

```
0 -1
0 0 -1
0 1 0 -1
0 6 7 0 -1
0 7 0 -1
0 0 -1
0 -1
0 1 0 -1
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried this?

Comment: @cigien output was wrong (different from the first one)

Comment: Please add that information (output of both pieces of code) to the question.

Comment: You have to print the output in reverse. So you need to store the numbers somewhere then print it out backwards.

Comment: as @0x499602D2 suggested your iterative code is printing child to parent. Use an array to store the values and print them in reverse order.

Comment: @cigien I have done that

Comment: Note that the recursive function walks the array in some way, until it reaches a stop, while remembering in the stack all the passages: only then it starts to print. So you should use an array to hold the intermediate results. If you show us the starting data and the call to the function we can understand better and verify our ideas before posting an answer.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica The exact code I am working with can be found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-paths-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question, I get the parent array as:

```
int parent[] = {-1,0,1,2,5,6,7,0,2};
```

I also run your code :

```
void printPath(int parent[], int j) 
{   
    int temp = parent[j];

    while (temp != - 1)
    {
        temp = parent[temp];
        printf("%d ", temp);

    }
}
```

Now three things to note:

1) Initialize `int temp = j` and not with `parent[j]`. This makes sure that you start with your path from `j` and not from `parent[j]`.

2) Instead of doing this:

```
temp = parent[temp];
printf("%d ", temp);
```

do this:

```
printf("%d ", temp);
temp = parent[temp];
```

This makes sure that you first print j and then parent[j].

After making the above changes your output will look like this:

```
1 0 
2 1 0 
3 2 1 0 
4 5 6 7 0 
5 6 7 0 
6 7 0 
7 0 
8 2 1 0
```

Now the last note.

3) To get the desired output you need to print in reverse order. One way is to first count the elements in the path. Then create an array of that size. Traverse again starting from `j` and store the elements in the array. After that you can print the array in reverse order.

After making these changes we get the following code:

```
void printPath(int parent[], int j) 
{   
    // Initialized temp from j
    int temp = j;

    // int variable that will store the number of elements in path
    int cnt=0;

    // traversing the path for first time to get count of elements in path
    while (temp != - 1)
    {
        cnt++;
        temp = parent[temp];
    }

    // creating array of cnt size
    int arr[cnt];

    // traversing the path for second time.
    // this time we will store elements in the array
    temp = j;
    int i=0;

    while(temp!=-1){
        arr[i++]=temp;
        temp = parent[temp];
    }

    // printing the elements in reverse order
    for(int i=cnt-1;i>=0;i--)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}
```

The above code will give you the correct output (as you mentioned):

```
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 7 6 5 4 
0 7 6 5 
0 7 6 
0 7 
0 1 2 8
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning, (it was...) untested code :-)**

As stated in comment, the recursive function walks the array in some way, until it reaches a stop, while remembering in the stack all the passages: only then it starts to print. So you should use an array to hold the intermediate results.

```
void printPath(int parent[], int j) {
  int  revert[V];    // to reverse; "V" is a costant (==9, size of vector)
  int  count=0;      // perhaps not needed, is assumed to always reach V
  int  temp;

  // unroll and store
  temp = j;         // edited; my temp=parent[j] was wrong
  while (temp) {
    revert[count++] = temp;
    temp = parent[temp];
  }

  // print reversed
  while (count) {
    count--;
    printf("%d ", revert[count]);
  }
}
```

I am not sure that this routine works, can not test now. In your original temptative there was an error because by doing

```
    temp = parent[temp];
    printf("%d ", temp);
```

it outputs even a -1, because it first prints, and then checks.

Hope this helps, I tried to correct the error and implement the reversing.

Comment: Tested the code. Replace `temp = parent[j];` with `temp = j`. The code misses the last digit. Suggested it as an edit

Comment: Tested too, please include the suggestion in your solution so I can mark it as the answer

Comment: Thak you @AbhayAravinda and Java, it is curious that a short routine like this is difficult to comprehend totally, but the team working is effective.

Answer (score 0):

Before dealing with an iterative one, your recursive solution needs a fix as it can't display the path for child 0:

```
void printPath_recursive(int parent_of[], int child)
{
    int parent = parent_of[child];

    if (parent != -1)
    {
        printPath_recursive(parent_of, parent);
    }

    printf("%d ", child); 
}
```

The iterative solution is along the lines that folks have suggested:

```
int parent_map[] = {-1, 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 0, 2};

#define PARENT_MAP_LENGTH (sizeof(parent_map) / sizeof(parent_map[0]))

void printPath_iterative(int parent_of[], int child) 
{
    int s = 0, ancestry[PARENT_MAP_LENGTH];

    while (child != -1)
    {
        ancestry[s++] = child;

        child = parent_of[child];
    }

    while (s > 0)
    {
        printf("%d ", ancestry[--s]);
    }
}
```

Output for either:

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 7 6 5 4
0 7 6 5
0 7 6
0 7
0 1 2 8
```